# Laravel Scout and TNTSearch search withTrashed

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I've configured Laravel Scout and can use `::search()` on my models.
The same models also use `SoftDeletes.` How can I combine the `::search()` with `withTrashed()`?

The code below does not work.

```
MyModel::search($request->input('search'))->withTrashed()->paginate(10);
```

The below does work but does not include the trashed items.

```
MyModel::search($request->input('search'))->paginate(10);
```

**Update 1**
I found in the [scout/ModelObserver](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/1.0/src/ModelObserver.php#L87) that deleted items are made unsearchable.  Which is a bummer; I wanted my users to be able to search through their trash.

**Update 2**
I tried using `::withoutSyncingToSearch,` as suggested by @camelCase, which I had high hopes for, but this also didn't work.

```php
$model = MyModel::withTrashed()->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

if ($model->deleted_at) {
    $model->forceDelete();
} else {
    MyModel::withoutSyncingToSearch(function () use ($model) {
        $model->delete();
    });
}
```

This caused an undefined offset when searching for a deleted item.  By the way, I'm using the TNTSearch driver for Laravel Scout. I don't know if this is an error with TNTSearch or with Laravel Scout.

Comment: Does `MyModel::search(...)->paginate(10)` give you a collection of models including the ones that are trashed or without?

Comment: I haven't dug into Scout enough yet but I'd assume deleted data isn't defined as searchable data.

Comment: You could rewrite that observer to adapt it to your needs. Or even make a pull request in order to transform that into an option

Comment: @El_Matella, you probably could, I don't think I could ;-)  I am just a noob user of scout.  Literally started using it yesterday.

Comment: While I haven't attempted this, what about using the `withoutSyncingToSearch` method to [pause indexing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout#pausing-indexing) while deleting records? I believe that will stop `unsearchable()` from being called.

Comment: Looks like I'm more a noob than you looking at your SO reputation :) . If you already have identified a behaviour that you think is not the best in the package, you can easily change it, even if your code is not the best in the world. You must start somewhere in the Open Source World, and it seems to me that this is a perfect example to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out a solution to your issue. I'll be submitting a `pull request` for `Scout` to hopefully get it merged with the official package.

This approach allows you to *include* soft deleted models in your search:

```
App\User::search('search query string')->withTrashed()->get();
```

To only show soft deleted models in your search:

```
App\User::search('search query string')->onlyTrashed()->get();
```

You need to modify 3 files:

**Builder.php**

In `laravel\scout\src\Builder.php` add the following:

```
/**
 * Whether the search should include soft deleted models.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $withTrashed = false;

/**
 * Whether the search should only include soft deleted models.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $onlyTrashed = false;

/**
 * Specify the search should include soft deletes
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function withTrashed()
{
    $this->withTrashed = true;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Specify the search should only include soft deletes
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function onlyTrashed()
{
    $this->onlyTrashed = true;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Paginate the given query into a simple paginator.
 *
 * @param  int  $perPage
 * @param  string  $pageName
 * @param  int|null  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
public function paginate($perPage = null, $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
{
    $engine = $this->engine();

    $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

    $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage();

    $results = Collection::make($engine->map(
        $rawResults = $engine->paginate($this, $perPage, $page), $this->model, $this->withTrashed, $this->onlyTrashed
    )); // $this->withTrashed, $this->onlyTrashed is new

    $paginator = (new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $engine->getTotalCount($rawResults), $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => $pageName,
    ]));

    return $paginator->appends('query', $this->query);
}
```

**Engine.php**

In `laravel\scout\src\Engines\Engine.php` modify the following:

```
/**
 * Map the given results to instances of the given model.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $results
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @param  boolean  $withTrashed // New
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
abstract public function map($results, $model, $withTrashed, $onlyTrashed); // $withTrashed, $onlyTrashed is new

/**
 * Get the results of the given query mapped onto models.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Scout\Builder  $builder
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function get(Builder $builder)
{
    return Collection::make($this->map(
        $this->search($builder), $builder->model, $builder->withTrashed, $builder->onlyTrashed // $builder->withTrashed, $builder->onlyTrashed is new
    ));
}
```

And finally, you just need to modify your relative search engine. I'm using Algolia, but the `map` method appears to be the same for `TNTSearch`.

**AlgoliaEngine.php**

In `laravel\scout\src\Engines\AlgoliaEngine.php` modify the `map` method to match the `abstract` class we modified above:

```
/**
 * Map the given results to instances of the given model.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $results
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @param  boolean  $withTrashed // New
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function map($results, $model, $withTrashed, $onlyTrashed) // $withTrashed, $onlyTrashed is new
{
    if (count($results['hits']) === 0) {
        return Collection::make();
    }

    $keys = collect($results['hits'])
                    ->pluck('objectID')->values()->all();

    $modelQuery = $model->whereIn(
        $model->getQualifiedKeyName(), $keys
    );

    if ($withTrashed) $modelQuery->withTrashed(); // This is where the query will include deleted items, if specified
    if ($onlyTrashed) $modelQuery->onlyTrashed(); // This is where the query will only include deleted items, if specified

    $models = $modelQuery->get()->keyBy($model->getKeyName());

    return Collection::make($results['hits'])->map(function ($hit) use ($model, $models) {
        $key = $hit['objectID'];

        if (isset($models[$key])) {
            return $models[$key];
        }
    })->filter();
}
```

**TNTSearchEngine.php**

```
/**
 * Map the given results to instances of the given model.
 *
 * @param mixed                               $results
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function map($results, $model, $withTrashed, $onlyTrashed)
{
    if (count($results['ids']) === 0) {
        return Collection::make();
    }

    $keys = collect($results['ids'])->values()->all();

    $model_query = $model->whereIn(
        $model->getQualifiedKeyName(), $keys
    );

    if ($withTrashed) $model_query->withTrashed();
    if ($onlyTrashed) $model_query->onlyTrashed();

    $models = $model_query->get()->keyBy($model->getKeyName());

    return collect($results['ids'])->map(function ($hit) use ($models) {
        if (isset($models[$hit])) {
            return $models[$hit];
        }
    })->filter();
}
```

Let me know how it works.

**NOTE**: This approach still requires you to manually pause syncing using the `withoutSyncingToSearch` method while deleting a model; otherwise the search criteria will be updated with `unsearchable()`.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it out!  BTW, just some feedback, can you call it 'withTrashed' to match the existing functionality in your pull request?

Comment: @JoshPetitt I was just looking at the naming convention thinking, "That doesn't make sense" :) Good catch, let me adjust and test any conflicts.

Comment: @JoshPetitt all set, updated naming convention. Ideally I'd write some type of check on the model observer so one didn't have to manually pause syncing when deleting...but for now, manually pausing works.

Comment: Okay, so I'm still getting an undefined offset error, but it is in the TeamTNT\Scout\Engines\TNTSearchEngine.php, so I would say your fix (if it works for Algolia) is good to go.  I'm gonna see if I can't figure out what to do with the TNTSearchEngine.  BTW it still works for searching without using withTrashed, so I don't think your change broke existing functionality.  I'd say it is good enough to pull request, and also THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @JoshPetitt Thanks for the feedback. Sorry to hear it's not working with that driver, hopefully some digging will sort it out. I have to imagine it's related to that `map` function (that's where all my debugging went during testing) and upon further inspection, it does differ slightly from Algolia. Good luck!

Comment: BOOM!  Got it working!  Turned out to be a typo in my code <sheepish>.  Yeah, your fix worked GREAT!

Comment: BTW, I added the edited map function for TNTSearchEngine.php for the next person, basically the same edits that you made for AlgoliaEngine

Comment: FYI, for your pull request, you may consider also supporting onlyTrashed.  I'm going to try an implement based on your previous answer, and if I can get it working I will update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution.

```
// will return matched ids of my model instance
$searchResultIds = MyModel::search($request->input('search'))->raw()['ids'];

MyModel::whereId('id', $searchResultIds)->onlyTrashed()->get();
```